# How to add user in Unix System 7?

Tags: useradd, historical-unix

I have created a Unix System 7 VM in VirtualBox following instructions [by Robert Nordier](https://www.nordier.com/articles/v7x86_vbox.html). I have dropped to the single user prompt (`#`). I can run commands like `ls` and `passwd` and `cat`. However, `useradd` is not found. Same is true for `adduser`. How do I add users in Unix System 7?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the following manually:

- find an available uid (with Robert Nordier’s images, uids 8 and greater are available):

  ```
  cat /etc/passwd
  ```
- find the appropriate primary gid (in V7, users didn’t have their own group; with Robert Nordier’s images, use 3, same as the guest account):

  ```
  cat /etc/group
  ```
- create the [`passwd`](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_7th/5/passwd) entry:

  ```
  echo 'login::uid:gid::/usr/login:' >> /etc/passwd
  ```

  (replacing `login`, `uid`, `gid` as appropriate; the above uses no password and the default shell)
- set the password:

  ```
  passwd login
  ```
- create the home directory.

Comment: Good lord. We have come quite a long way. Could you please add some pointers on finding "available uid" and "primary gid"? I can't even see what's in /bin. There is no pg, less, more or most. I had to dump ls into a file and view with vi. And vi was only available in the guest login.

Comment: @GunJack Maybe [the sysadmin's Rosetta Stone](https://bhami.com/rosetta.html) can help. The user creation method Stephen gives is described under SunOS 4.